# Errors on Page when using JSF1.2/Richfaces3.3.3 with IE8

Tags: jsf, internet-explorer-8, richfaces

I am forced to develop for IE8 and for the most parts it works fine, but I get some Errors like:

```
'SimpleTogglePanelManager' is undefined
'Richfaces' is undefined
Object expected
```

Doing a browser reload clears these errors, but clicking a button or link that leads me to antother page on the site creates these errors again.

Is there a way to fix that behavior?

Comment: Are you using HTTPS for your site? This problem can occur if the scripts are downloaded over HTTP.

Comment: As far as I remember, the script errors also occur when using HTTP, but I have to check again. If that were the case, how could I fix that?

Comment: Or the other way round, can also, it's only a much less common problem. Check if you aren't mixing HTTP and HTTPS on a single page and let me know.